# Add Object onStartPage itextPdf except the last Page

Tags: java, itext

I am adding a rectangle on top of my page for all pages but I do not want the rectangle on the last page. Here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document output) {
        Font bold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD);
        bold.setStyle(Font.UNDERLINE);
        bold.setColor(new BaseColor(171, 75, 15));
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        // Bottom left coordinates x & y, followed by width, height and radius of corners.
        cb.roundRectangle(100f, 1180f, 400f, 100f, 5f);//I dont want this on the ;ast page
        cb.stroke();
        try {
            output.add(new Paragraph("STATEMENT OF ACCOUNT", bold));
            output.add(new Paragraph(new Phrase(new Chunk(" "))));
            output.add(new Paragraph(new Phrase(new Chunk(" "))));
            output.add(new Paragraph(new Phrase(new Chunk(" "))));
            output.add(new Paragraph(new Phrase(new Chunk(" "))));
            Image logo = Image.getInstance(imagepath);
            logo.setAbsolutePosition(780, 1230);
            logo.scaleAbsolute(200, 180);
            writer.getDirectContent().addImage(logo);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to either skip or remove this rectangle from the last Page of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all iText developers often have stressed that in `onStartPage` one MUST NOT add content to the PDF. The reason is that under certain circumstances unused pages are created and `onStartPage` is called for them but they then are dropped. If you add content to them in `onStartPage`, though, they are not dropped but remain in your document.

Thus, always use `onEndPage` to add any content to a page.

---

In your use case there is yet another reason for using `onEndPage`: Usually it only becomes clear that a given page is the last page when the last bit of content has been added to the document. This usually occurs after `onStartPage` has been called for the page but before `onEndPage` has.

Thus, after you've added the last bit of regular page content to the document, you can simply set a flag in the page event listener that the current page is the final document page. Now the following `onEndPage` call knows it processes the final page and can add content differently.

So the page event listener would look like this

```
class MyPageEventListener extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    public boolean lastPage = false;

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document output) {
        if (!lastPage) {
            [add extra content for page before the last one]
        } else {
            [add extra content for last page]
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and be used like this

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, TARGET);
MyPageEventListener pageEventListener = new MyPageEventListener();
writer.setPageEvent(pageEventListener);
document.open();
[add all regular content to the document]
pageEventListener.lastPage = true;
document.close();
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not have the bit of information about adding contents at `onStartPage`. Your approach also worked excellently for my situation.